# Is result of items depending on Seer/Adj/WH check always dependant on role info?

Tags: werewolv.es

Do items rely on status given in role text or on status changed by certain items?

2 examples: Warg's Bracer is dependant on wolfpack kill. Does the role have to be actual member of wolfpack or can it be any player that appears as wolfpack, such as a militia with a Wolf Pelt or altered by Sanguine Horn? Same for Magi's Circlet and wh status: e.g. does it block everyone carrying a rune?